# Delphi - SQL - Determining when NO updates across multiple detail records within a time frame

Tags: sql, delphi, master-detail

I am writing an application for a Gym (Personal trainer type of organization).  I need to write a query, and I am needing help.

Athletes (table:Athlete)  buy blocks of time (table:Programs).  They make use of this time via appointments (table:Usage),

The query I need to write:  Show me the distinct (unique, i.e. only one record EACH) Athletes (I,e, First Name and Last Name) that are ACTIVE (Boolean field in the Athletes table) where the Athlete hasn’t “touched” his program in the last two weeks.

```
Structures:

ATHLETE Table
ID : Primary Key
ACTIVE:  Boolean Field
First Name
Last Name

PROGRAMS Table
PROGRAM_ID : Primary Key
ATHLETE_ID : Foreign Key
DATE_PURCHASED:  Date the program was purchased

USAGE Table
USAGE_ID : Primary Key
PROGRAM ID: Foreign Key to PROGRAMS table
ATHLETE_ID: Foreign Key to ATHLETE Table.
CREATED_DATE:  The date they created the appointment
SCHEDULED_DATE: The Time of the appointment
CHECKIN_IN: When they actually showed up
```

My SQL Syntax is SQL92, with CASE statement support. So, I need to see two different types of data.  (1)  Athletes who purchased a program at least two weeks ago, and have done nothing with it (i.e. the athlete has a program, but NO USAGE assigned to that program, and (2),  athletes who have programs which have one or more usages, but  there is NO usage which has EITHER CREATED_DATE or SCHEDULED_DATE more recent that two weeks ago.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select distinct First, Last
from   ATHLETE A
join   PROGRAMS P
on     P.ATHLETE_ID = A.ID
where  A.ACTIVE = 1
and    P.PROGRAM_ID not in (select PROGRAM_ID
                            from   USAGE
                            where  ATHLETE_ID     = A.ID
                            and    CREATED_DATE   >= dateadd(dd, -14, getdate())
                            or     SCHEDULED_DATE >= dateadd(dd, -14, getdate())
                           )
```

The sub-query selects all programs for the athlete that have been touched in the last two weeks. These are then excluded from the join of athletes and programs.